# Call GCP Document AI add authentication

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, http-post, cloud-document-ai

I need to call the GCP Document AI, specifically the OCR processor, from Swift using a base64 encoded image. However, when I send my request using the code from below, it always times out due to the missing authorization header. [Here's the link to the Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/ocr?hl=de&_ga=2.148510839.-1713196529.1622206174#online-process).

This is my request code so far:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://us-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us/processors/PROCESSOR_ID:process")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("""
            Bearer {
              "type": "service_account",
              "project_id": "*",
              "private_key_id": "*",
              "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n*\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
              "client_email": "*",
              "client_id": "*",
              "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
              "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
              "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
              "client_x509_cert_url": "*"
            }
            """, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.httpBody = """
    {
        "skipHumanReview": TRUE,
        "inlineDocument": {
        "mimeType": "image/tiff",
        "content": "\(image.pngData()!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))"
        }
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print("got some response...")
    guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else { // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
        return
    }
}

task.resume()
```

This is the console output:

```
2021-06-02 15:42:24.167939+0200 SchoolAid Pro[6418:1625073] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C3.1 2a00:1450:4001:830::200a.443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-06-02 15:42:24.168069+0200 SchoolAid Pro[6418:1625073] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C3.1 2a00:1450:4001:830::200a.443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

...which repeats as time passes, until it says `401 UNAUTHORIZED`, as expected.

This is the CMD command for sending a request taken from the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/ocr?hl=de&_ga=2.148510839.-1713196529.1622206174#online-process), which uses an environment variable for getting the authorization tokens, which is obviously not possible in Swift:

```bash
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://LOCATION-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/processors/PROCESSOR_ID:process
```

I am unsure, however, how I could add this authentication header to my request. Is there an easy way to do this, like to add something like `request.authHeader = ...` to the request?

Comment: I guess you need to check https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?hl=en#manually how to get one. Then, it be a variable in your app?

Comment: I got the JSON key file, but how can I integrate that into my request?

Comment: Let's analyze the `curl` command: For `-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"`, you wrote `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`, which by the way, why did the value changed from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So for `-H "Authorization: Bearer theValue`, same logic, no? Add it into the headers with `setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)`.

Comment: This is the code I used now: `request.setValue("private_key_id", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`, but I still get the `401 - UNAUTHORIZED` error. Passing the complete JSON I downloaded doesn't work either. Do you know which of the values I need to pass in order to work?

Comment: What happened to Bearer in your value?

Comment: You're totally right, I forgot about that one, but even then it still gives me the same error... do you have any other ideas on what could be wrong with my request?

Comment: If you edit your question with your current code? For the values, you should only have: `request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`. Is that the case?

Comment: I just updated the code, but it still doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233269/discussion-between-larme-and-frederik-brammer).

Comment: FYI, there is an actively monitored tag for Document AI [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)